# Dockerized angular api request url

Tags: angular, docker

i'm dockerizing my angular app that consumes a python container (in the same docker-compose) and almos all is working well but when frontend try to make an http request to the backend it uses a bad URL:

Docker Host URL: 192.168.1.11
FrontEnd port: 800
BackEnd port: 5000

The url request that browser try to reach: http://192.168.1.11:800/192.168.1.11:5000/api/...

It only happens when i try to deploy with docker. when i run muy project locally it works fine.

Comment: Can you try to add more information like the docker files and the docker-compose file? Also the code segment where your frontend tries to call the backend if possible.

Comment: sorry, in a desperate moment, I wrote the angular URL api whithout protocol. I just had to write 'http://' before my url's API. Thanks.